# What are these most tiny bugs called

Tags: species-identification, entomology

These bugs are the smallest bugs I've ever seen in my life and they are very annoying, throughout the day, I just feel sudden scratches on my body and when I look closely, the cause are these bugs moving on my body, they are making me lose my mind. They are hard to kill, putting pressure when they are between my fingers does not kill them, I need to press them against hard flat surface to kill them. They go inside my laptop, from the keyboard holes and touchpad which could possibly damage it and they are everywhere and there's a lot of them.

Here's an enlarged image of one of them moving on my monitor's screen:

[image: bug]

The rest of the images are not zoomed in so you can get a sense of how small they are, please zoom in on them as you wish:

[image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host] [image: image host]

What are these bugs called?

I've been googling a lot, the closest I could come up with was bed bugs and Argas reflexus and they are not either of those.